# When can I buy an Ubuntu tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

I read a lot of pdfs using Mendely and I want to buy an Ubuntu tablet for reading these pdfs on the go. I want to sync my pdf directory on my desktop (that's also running Ubuntu) with my tablet using rsync.

Question 1) When is a tablet with Ubuntu Touch installed going to be on the market?

Question 2) Shall I just buy a normal tablet and install Ubuntu on it? Can this be done easily with, say, a Samsung Galaxy Note?

Question 3) If I can install an application in Ubuntu, will I definitely be able to install it in Ubuntu touch? Will Ubuntu touch be incompatible with any Ubuntu apps?

I don't want to have to 'jailbreak' anything or do anything flakey. I just love Ubuntu, and I want it on the go. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1)Estimated at Q1-2015.

2)Yes you could do it,but that is basically jailbreaking.
As for the devices on which you could do that I suggest you carefully read this list:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices
But you could get the best results on Nexus devices because those are the devices used by the developers themselves for testing.